# How would you define a cryptography pairing on FourQ?

Tags: commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves, cryptography, bilinear-form

I'm interested in implementing [a pairing-based cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing-based_cryptography) operation on embedded systems. [Some background on pairings was discussed at Crypto.SE in [Advantages of bilinear map](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/advantages-of-bilinear-map).]

Previously I analyzed the fourQ-lib, and next I would like to write or clone a pairing operation. But there I need some crowd knowledge:

- Does anyone knows about a working pairing for FourQ (twisted edwards curve)?
- How would you declare such a bilinear map mathematically?

The FourQ curve is a twisted Edward's curve over $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ given by the equation $-x^2+y^2= 1 +dx^2y^2$, where $\mathbb F_{p^2}=\mathbb F_p(i)$ and $d\in\mathbb C$ a big complex integer. (If there could be a mention of Gaussian integers, these are $a+ib$ with $a,b\in\mathbb N$.) The inverse of a point is given by $(x,y) \to (-x,y)$, neutral element is $\mathcal O=(0,1)$. 
The prime order subgroup $E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})[N]$, where $\# E(\mathbb F_{p^2}))392\cdot N$, is used to carry out crypto. computations.

This torsion set could be seen as a(n affine) variety.

Comment: I took a quick look through Crypto.SE and found several Questions that touch on "twisted edwards" curves and one mention of FourQ.  There are several dozen Questions about "tag:pairings" in cryptography.  My impression is that more background needs to be added to this Question to make it accessible to a "crowd" of Math.SE Readers.

Comment: What do u think should be required for answering? It's about commutative algebra I guess.

Comment: I added a couple of links in the body of the Question.  Clearly we want $p$ to be an odd prime for which $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod $p$, i.e. we ask that $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.

Comment: Googling finds [a 2008 proceedings paper](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/30698012/Steven_Galbraith_PairingBased_Cryptography_Pair.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1496764398&Signature=fRkzg4YcIoklqgFo235VRlM8MDI%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DExponentiation_in_pairing-friendly_group.pdf#page=201)  titled "Pairing Computation on Twisted Edwards Form Elliptic Curves" by Das and Sarkar.

Comment: A more recent (2013) paper is [The Pairing Computation on Edwards Curves](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2013/136767/) by Wu, Li, and Zhang. The article is open-access (Math. Problems in Engineering).

Comment: Hm.. am I right, that FourQ is not that performant for the Tate-pairing, since the embedding degree is "(N-1)/2", where N is a 245-bit prime.

Comment: Have a look at [1] section 2. 


[1] https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/565.pdf

Comment: Surely $d$ must be an element of $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ rather than a complex number.

Comment: You could take $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ as the extension field $\mathbb F_p(i)$ and, therefore, d could be a complex number with integers in $\mathbb F_p$. :-)